# iOS multiple HTML5 audio status

Tags: ios, html5-audio

It is documented all over the web that the iOS does not support multiple HTML5 audio. I ran a test and here are the observation:

1. iOS 5 (iPad1) - can play only one audio at a time.
2. iOS 6 (iPad2) - can play multiple audio.
3. iOS 7 (iPad3) - can play multiple audio.

It looks like on iOS 6 & 7, we can play multiple HTML5 audio, but to my surprise i could not find any discussion regarding this over the web, also [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW10) still says  "Currently, all devices running iOS are limited to playback of a single audio or video stream at any time"

I am not sure if multiple HTML5 audio will work across all devices which support iOS6 and iOS7, also will apple continue to support this with next version of iOS, does anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: On iOS 10 it seems from my tests that I can only play one audio at a time.